# I need the name of a Sci-Fi/Fantasy Book Series

Tags: story-identification

When I was a kid my stepdad at the time read a book series about a family or group of people that could walk through portals or time travel to other universes or something like that.  I want to say it had some comedy in it, but also that it was for adults.  That's why I never got to read it as a kid.  I remember something about a main character getting blinded/tortured.  He talked about the series like it was really awesome.  If I'm not mistaken he travelled all over the place to used bookstores to find the whole series (because internet wasn't available) because it was difficult to find.  I know this isn't a lot of info, but I want to read the series and I haven't talked to the guy since I was 11 (I'm 25 now).  Thanks!

Comment: Any recollection of the cover artistry?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be [Roger Zelany](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Zelazny)'s *[The Chronicles of Amber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber)* though I am a little concern that the series has only a few very modest "adult" scenes.

Two five book cycles each containing a complete story (with a certain episodic nature that makes the individual volumes reasonably self-contained), now available in [a single large volume *The Great Book of Amber*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380809060). There is also a prequal series written by another author after Zelany's death.

The protagonist of the first cycle, Corwin of Amber, is blinded and imprisoned in the first book.

> He regenerates his eyes and effects his escape right at the end of the book. Whereupon he sends forth a "black bird of my desire" and "a white bird of my desire" to carry messages across the universes.

Corwin is a member of a family uniquely gifted with a set of abilities related to moving between (or perhaps creating) any universes that they can imagine, and the Earth that we know and inhabit is but one of the multitude of "shadows" that they can visit. Amber is the name of the true world of which all the shadows are mere reflections.

Tags on SciFi.SE realted: [roger-zelazny](/questions/tagged/roger-zelazny), [amber](/questions/tagged/amber).

Comment: dmckee, thanks!  from your description i actually believe that is te series after i looked it up.  too bad there isn't a kindle version :-(.  looks like i'll go old school!