# What book had a character who could control magical strands or streams?

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a title of a book, The main character could send out a "strand, stream?" of magic to retrieve whatever he wished.  If he wanted a beer he would get it and one would disappear elsewhere in the world. I know I read the book as a paperback, maybe in the mid to late 90's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds to me like Roger Zelazny's [Trumps of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Amber#The_Merlin_Cycle) series. The principal character - Merlin of Chaos - accesses magic via the Logrus. When using this he visualises lines of magic extending from his hands, and on several occasions uses this abliity to draw beers to himself.
There are 5 books in the series, Trumps of Doom, Blood of Amber, Sign of Chaos, Knight of Shadows and Prince of Chaos.

Comment: He also retrieved corkscrews, swords, and on one memorable occasion a ladder which showed signs of having left an angry painter on the ground where it came from.

Comment: Oh, Thank You so much.  I have searched my memory and could not remember.  I KNEW it had something to do with Amber.  I recently purchased and started reading the collection of Amber Novels in one book.  I appreciate you answering my question.

Comment: see also this question about a related series: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32398/i-need-the-name-of-a-sci-fi-fantasy-book-series

Answer (score 1):

The Wheel of Time series, by Robert Jordan

> (and later picked up by Brandon Sanderson after the original author's death in 2007)

The strands are weaved into different spells - one can infuse orange scent (hopefully), another would slice armor in half, etc. They come in five different flavours - the classical five elements of spirit, air, earth, fire and water. The source of these is known as the Power, which is divided into two halves - one called *saidar*, which is the female half, and *saidin*, which is the male half and tainted by the Dark Lord.

> Until book 10.

It's a behemoth of a series, effectively quadruple the length of Lord of the Rings, and has much more diplomacy besides. I'd definitely recommend a few years to reading it.

Comment: I don't remember Rand, Mat, or Perrin ever sending out a strand of magic to get a beer and the beer disappearing somewhere else in the world.

Comment: Yeah, I am a huge fan of WoT, and while at first I thought this may be what the OP was asking for, I quickly realized it wasn't

Comment: the Lost Talent of beeretrieval?

Comment: It WAS Trumps of Doom.  BUT thank you for reminding me of this series as well as I read it when younger and would like to revisit that world as well.  I am taking a break from the computer and trying to read a little more.